# How to make custom class apply to foreach usage

Tags: c#, foreach

KeyValuePair struct has read-only properties (Key and Value), so I made a custom class in order to replace it:

```
public class XPair<T, U>
{
    // members
    private KeyValuePair<T, U> _pair;

    // constructors
    public XPair()
    {
        _pair = new KeyValuePair<T, U>();
    }
    public XPair(KeyValuePair<T, U> pair)
    {
        _pair = pair;
    }

    // methods
    public KeyValuePair<T, U> pair
    {
        get { return _pair; }
        set { _pair = value; }
    }
    public T key
    {
        get { return _pair.Key; }
        set { _pair = new KeyValuePair<T, U>(value, _pair.Value); }
    }
    public U value
    {
        get { return _pair.Value; }
        set { _pair = new KeyValuePair<T, U>(_pair.Key, value); }
    }
}
```

Is it possible for this class to also apply to "foreach" usage with Dictionary? Example:

```
Dictionary<String, Object> dictionary = fillDictionaryWithData();
foreach(XPair<String, Object> pair in dictionary) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite the keys or values?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I would think about updating the _dictionary_ rather than trying to update the key-value pairs.

Comment: I just wanted to replace KeyValuePair struct with a more flexible one. XPair is a struct I was using anyway, so I thought I could also use it in the "foreach" command instead of KeyValuePair. I guess it's not necessary after all. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be possible if your class would implement a conversion operator from `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

But it still wouldn't work the way you expect, because changing the key or the value of `pair` inside the loop will have no effect on the `dictionary`. Key and value in the dictionary will remain unchanged.

If you want to change the value inside a dictionary, simply use `dictionary[key] = newValue;`

If you want to change a key, I guess that you don't really want a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. An `IEnumerable<XPair<TKey, TValue>>` might be more appropriate.
If you really need a Dictionary, you can use the following code to "change" a key:

```
var value = dictionary[key];
dictionary.Remove(key);
dictionary.Add(newKey, value);
```